# How to count characters with jQueryTe?

Tags: jquery

This script works fine without jQueryTE (http://jqueryte.com/).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myTextarea").keyup(function(){
    el = $(this);
    if(el.val().length >= 300){
      el.val( el.val().substr(0, 300) );
    } else {
      $("#count").text(300-el.val().length);
    }
  });
});
```

How to count characters with jQueryTE? 
I have tried use the class "jqte_editor" but, doesn't work for me ( don't return nothing!).

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps var val = $(".editor").jqteVal();

Comment: Thank you Mplungjan, but doesn't work for me.

Comment: The solution:

Replace  $("#myTextarea")   for $(".jqte_editor") 
Replace   the word   'val'    for word   'text' 

Thank you so much.